# SQL column not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i am trying to apply whereRaw method on a laravel collection

```
return Auth::user()->friends()->whereRaw('CONCAT(friend.first_name," ",friend.last_name) LIKE \''.$fullName.'%\'')->get();
```

i am getting this error :

> message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'friend.first_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `friends` where (`friends`.`user_id` = 46 and `friends`.`user_id` is not null or `friend_id` = 46 and CONCAT(friend.first_name," ",friend.last_name) LIKE 'ffff%') and `friends`.`deleted_at` is null)"

menawhile the columns first_name and last_name already exists

Comment: Change `friend.first_name` to `friends.first_name` (friend"s")

Comment: And because of [Sql injection attacks](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), use the `setBindings` to define your parameters for your "where" condition (do not merge values in your query string). Like `...->whereRaw('... like ?')->setBindings(['anything'])`

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your table is called `friends` and not `friend`. So, change your code to :

```
return Auth::user()->friends()->whereRaw('CONCAT(friends.first_name," ",friends.last_name) LIKE \''.$fullName.'%\'')->get();
```